# PowerApps attachments from sharepoint forms does not work (unsaved status)

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I recently created my first Power App.
In this PowerApp i have connect with Sharepoint list. On one of the screens I have an attachment box (with default settings - I haven't changed anything.

1. Attachments are allowed on my list.
2. Data Card is in a new mode (in edit mode it is not visible).

So right now I can play this app and this attachment form does have a logic. I can select attachment to add it is is OK. But this attachment has a status UNSAVED.

And when I save my whole form with attachment with function:
SubmitForm(Form2),
The attachment is not saved. It is not visible on Sharepoint List.

On attachment page I have formula on button:

SubmitForm(Form1) && SubmitForm(Form2);;
ResetForm(Form1) && ResetForm(Form2);;
Navigate(Screen4;Fade)

Form1 is Sharepoint List multiline text
Form2 is Attachment from Sharepoint List

Multiline text is saved. All seems good, but no attachments are to be found.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.
You cannot use multiple Submit. You have to use Patch.